# Oracle function for scoring date intervals, inverse of months_between

Tags: sql, oracle, statistics, intervals

I have a set of `(employeeId, planId, coverageMonth, contractId)` keys.    Sometimes there are two or more (contractId)s for each  `(employeeId, planId, coverageMonth)` i.e.

```
1,1,'1-Jan-2011','contract0'  
1,1,'1-Feb-2011','contract0'  
1,1,'1-Mar-2011','contract0'  
1,1,'1-Apr-2011','contract0'  
1,1,'1-May-2011','contract0'  

1,1,'1-Jun-2011','contract0'  
1,1,'1-Jun-2011','contract1'  

1,1,'1-Jul-2011','contract1'  
1,1,'1-Aug-2011','contract1'  
1,1,'1-Sep-2011','contract1'  
1,1,'1-Oct-2011','contract1'  
1,1,'1-Nov-2011','contract1'
```

I've gotten the month having duplicate contractIds in one month via

```
...  
group by employeeId, planId, coverageMonth  
having count(distinct contractId) > 1
```

I've also expanded these keys out to  `(employeeId, planId, coverageMonth, contractId)`  via `EXISTS` (or `IN`).

I'm trying to find the best contractId for the  each duplicates month record.

I want to find all months around the duplicate contract month and give each a score (the  closer the month is, the higher the score,  the farther out it is, the lower the score).

I want to sum the scores and the highest score decides which contractId is to be used in the duplicate month.

Problem is that the `months_between()` returns small values for near months and large values
for far months.  I need the inverse of this.

Is there a way to set scores on other month records so that if a month is closer, it has
a better score?  That way, when I aggregate/sum the scores, the best score (closest and largest clump of months) gets to determine the definitive contractId for the
month with duplicate contractIds.

I'm working in SQL / Oracle.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The closer the month, the higher the score, the farther away from the duplicate month, the lower the score. It could be an integer score or a rational number given by a finite decimal representation.

Comment: You could use an arbitrary constant with your months_between(), like (100 - months_between()).  That would make the closer months return a higher value.

Comment: What do you mean by "all months around"? May an d July in your example? Or Jul- Nov for contract 1 and Jan-May for contract0?

Comment: @Jens Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May would have individual scores and Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov would also have individual scores. All months around.

Comment: @Lost What if the number of months_between exceeds 100?

Comment: @Dragos Toader, I think the negative still would work for you. It's just an arbitrary number.  Use 1000 if you think 100 would be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 1/months_between() or SOME_HUGE_VALUE-months_between()

Anyway, you might want to look into analytic functions looks like you have a problem that analytic functions are made for.

Comment: I'd get into trouble with 1/months_between() as I would need higher and higher scale. (more digits after the decimal point)  With the HUGE_VALUE, I would get into trouble in the later aggregation step where I would probably cross the precision boundary for the SUM field.

Comment: I'll find the upper boundary max() into variable for months_between (across the whole dataset) first, then use that to set the upper bound. Thanks, I've gotten unstuck :)

Comment: I used SUM(TRUNC(( 1 / POWER(2,ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(d.coverageMonth,p.coverageMonth))-1))*10000000)) where d is the table containing the keys we need the score for and p is the table joined in on the common compound key where d.coverageMonth != p.coverageMonth